# Hibernate: Select where in a OneToMany relation

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, jpql

These are my (abbreviated) entities:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="user_items",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id"),inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="useritem_id"))
    private Set<UserItem> items = Sets.newHashSet();

}


@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class UserItem {

    @Id
    @Type(type=EntityConstants.TYPE_UUID)
    @Column(columnDefinition=EntityConstants.COL_UUID)
    private UUID id;

}

@Entity
public class UserItemFurniture extends UserItem {

}
```

Now I want to get a `UserItemFurniture` by its UUID, but only if it is present a `User`'s `items`. This is my attempt:

```
em
    .createQuery(
        "SELECT f " +
        "FROM UserItemFurniture f " +
        "WHERE f.id = :iid " +
        "AND f IN (SELECT u.items FROM User u WHERE u.id = :uid) ",
        UserItemFurniture.class
    )
    .setParameter("uid", userId)
    .setParameter("iid", itemId)
    .getSingleResult();
```

But it generates this nonsensical SQL:

```
select useritemfu0_.id as id17_, useritemfu0_1_.item as item17_, useritemfu0_.roomNumber as roomNumber18_, useritemfu0_.x as x18_, useritemfu0_.y as y18_
from UserItemFurniture useritemfu0_ inner join UserItem useritemfu0_1_ on useritemfu0_.id=useritemfu0_1_.id
where useritemfu0_.id=? and (useritemfu0_.id in (
    select .
    from _User user1_, user_items items2_, UserItem useritem3_
    where user1_.id=items2_.user_id and items2_.useritem_id=useritem3_.id and user1_.id=?
))
limit ?
```

(note the subquery: `SELECT .`)

Can I do this without resorting to native or multiple queries? Note that `UserItem` does not have a reference to `User`, which is by design.

Comment: Have you tried restricting by `id` the `IN` clause? Something like `...AND f.id IN (SELECT u.items.id FROM User ...`

Comment: It is not possible to use u.items.id, because items as a collection valued path refers to whole collection and consequently it does not have attribute id (even that elements of collection do have).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following query can be used:

```
SELECT f
FROM UserItemFurniture f
WHERE f.id = :uid AND EXISTS 
  (SELECT u FROM User u
   WHERE u.id = :iid and f MEMBER OF u.items)
```